# The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified. I've tried many times to use column but it didnt solve my problem

Tags: flutter, dart

i've tried to use columns to solve my problems but it doenst work. It still say

"The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified."
I don't know what to do and i try to learn flutter and dart so if someone have the answer please explain to me.

Thank you

This is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Hero());
}

class Hero extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Kerby promo"),
            ),
           
            floatingActionButton:
                FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                      color: Colors.orange),
                  child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('holla');
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_rounded)),
                      Spacer(),
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('holla');
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.portrait))
                    ],
                  ),
                  child:
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Column(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('holla');
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_rounded)),
                    Spacer(),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('holla');
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.portrait))
                  ],
                      ),
                    )),
                  //child: Column(children: [IconButton(onPressed:  () {print('holla');}, icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_rounded)),])
                )))));
  }
}
```

Hi, i've tried to use columns to solve my problems but it doenst work. It still say

"The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified."
I don't know what to do and i try to learn flutter and dart so if someone have the answer please explain to me.

Thank you
Hi, i've tried to use columns to solve my problems but it doenst work. It still say

"The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified."
I don't know what to do and i try to learn flutter and dart so if someone have the answer please explain to me.

Thank you
èHi, i've tried to use columns to solve my problems but it doenst work. It still say

"The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified."
I don't know what to do and i try to learn flutter and dart so if someone have the answer please explain to me.

Thank you

Comment: First, tell me what design are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, i want my app to look like this: 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OPY8qOiAnUZC4xiAIn2s7DiCMb-o7RL_23WwKOgHs3M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Hero());
}

class Hero extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hero({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Kerby promo"),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 500,
              width: 300,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                  color: Colors.orange),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                // ignore: avoid_print
                                print('holla');
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_rounded)),
                          const Spacer(),
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                // ignore: avoid_print
                                print('holla');
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.portrait))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                // ignore: avoid_print
                                print('holla');
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_rounded)),
                          
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                // ignore: avoid_print
                                print('holla');
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.portrait))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Expanded(
                  //   child: Column(children: [
                  //     IconButton(
                  //         onPressed: () {
                  //           print('holla');
                  //         },
                  //         icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_return_rounded)),
                  //   ]),
                  // )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you just removed the second widget. I need that widget but down. Can you help me please

Comment: Do you mean you need the buttons on four corners?

Comment: I want it to look more like this 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OPY8qOiAnUZC4xiAIn2s7DiCMb-o7RL_23WwKOgHs3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I edited the code, it should looks how you wanted.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much. What was my mistake?

Comment: What you tried to do is, you passed two child widgets to a Container( ) but it can only take one.

Comment: Passing a Column( ) to the Container( ) allowed it to take both Row( ) widgets as children of the Column( )